# Need to know if I need a third model for joining Users with another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, has-many

I have two models, pit and user. Pit is basically a glorified post model. Its a discussion in which users participate. I basically would like it if I could have users "join" a pit and then be associated with that pit. I've done some searching on here and I'm not quite sure whether I need to create another "group" model or not. Users can have many pits and I also want them to able to belong to many pits via join. I'm new at this and really don't want to screw it up so would like some advice before embarking on this task. Thanks for any advice.

Current Pit model

```
class Pit < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :topic, :author, :summary, presence: true
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_votable
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
```

Current User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
  has_many :pits
  has_many :comments
```

Based on my searches via this site and google I'm getting the feeling that I maybe need to create a separate "group" model with a  "has_many_through" but I don't want to over complicate things if this is not needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [has_and_belongs_to_many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

This will enable each user to have many pits and each pit can have many users. It will give you access to methods such as:

`@user.pits` - will return all the pits to which a user belongs
`@pit.users` - will return all the users who belong to a particular pit

You will need to [manually create, via a migration, the join table](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-join-table) which should be called `pits_users` and which will have two columns, `pit_id` and `user_id`.  You will need to update both your Pit and User models to the following:

```
class Pit < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pits
```

When a user joins a pit, you could write code as follows:

```
@pit.users.create(@current_user)
```

This will add an entry in the join table consisting of the pit id and user id.

Comment: This is what I was looking for Robin. Thanks. Just wasn't quite sure. Appreciate the help.